# Handling unicode characters in folder path (FileSystemObject, .CreateFolder

Tags: excel, vba, unicode

I deploy a macro that saves a lot of Excel files to a defined folder structure. These folders are created by the macro, and the Excel files are then saved to the folders. This macro reads the folder paths of each to-be-created Excel file from another Excel file, and does that in a lot of different languages that are also read from this file.

I use the following function to handle folder/path creation, which is called before the Excel file is saved to the folder:

```vb
Function MakeDir(Path As String)
    Const ProcessName As String = "MakeDir"
    'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set FileSysObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    If Path = "" Then
        Call ErrorHandle("Übersetzungsinformation", "Leerer Pfad", "Es wurde versucht, ein Verzeichnis mit leerem Pfad zu erstellen.", "")
    End If
    
    If Not FileSysObj.FolderExists(Path) Then FileSysObj.CreateFolder Trim(Path)
    
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    Call ErrorHandle(ProcessName, Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.HelpContext)
    End
End Function
```

Because this folder path includes Unicode characters, specifically Slowak characters like `Č`, this throws runtime error 76, saying the path can't be found. When I run the same code replacing `Č` with a standard `C`, it works fine.

I previously had a similar function using `MkDir()` instead of `FileSystemObject`, but after a bit of research found that this does in fact not support Unicode characters, and that `FileSystemobject` should in theory be able to handle these.

Is there something else I'm missing here? I'd appreciate your help a lot.

I tried setting the system locale to Slowak, and the macro ran without a problem. However, this is not a permanent solution, as the macro is deployed on several different systems, and also uses several different languages with different Unicode characters.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not reproduce your problem, creating directories even containing obscure Unicode characters like  or Č works fine for me when using the FSO. I do get error 76 when trying to use `MkDir`as expected.

Comment: @GWD That is strange. Thank you for checking! Then it might have to do something with the system version my organization is using? I need to check this on another machine at work. Cheers!